# Delegate and Protocol code not entering delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am working on an user activation errors, I have a NSObject class that gets call if an error is returned from the DB.

I show an alertview that has a method called when the user presses the UIButton on the alert view. This is what the method looks like.

**//ErrorHandling.m**

```objectivec
//
case 1: {
            NSLog(@"ERROR = 1");
            message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error 1:"
                                                 message:@"The activation request failed."
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];

            message.tag = myAlertViewsTag;
            [self performSelector:@selector(showAlertViewAndMessage) withObject:message afterDelay:0.3]; // set timer to give any huds time to load so I can unload them correctly
        }
            break;
//

- (void)showAlertViewAndMessage {
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    [message show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView.tag == myAlertViewsTag) {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {

                if (receivedResponseData != nil) {

                    if (errorCodeValue == 1) {
                        [[self errorDataDelegate] passErrorDataToRoot:receivedResponseData];
                    }

                    // incase the user is further on in the navigationstack bring them back to the rootview
                    [self.currentNavigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                }
        }
}
```

so far all this code works, accept for the delegate/protocol request... I have checked and double checked my code, however I think maybe I am missing something that maybe you can see. This is what my Delegate and Protocol looks like.

**//errorHandling.h**

```objectivec
@protocol RecivedErrorData <NSObject>
- (void)passErrorDataToRoot:(NSData *)errorData;
@end

//Protocol/delegate
 __weak id <RecivedErrorData> errorDataDelegate;

//Protocol/delegate
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <RecivedErrorData> errorDataDelegate;
```

**//errorHandling.m**

```objectivec
//delegate / protocols
@synthesize errorDataDelegate;

[[self errorDataDelegate] passErrorDataToRoot:receivedResponseData];
```

**//RootViewController.h**

```objectivec
#import "ErrorHandling.h"
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <RecivedErrorData> {
// error handling for activations
ErrorHandling *errorHandling;
```

**//RootViewController.m**

```objectivec
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    errorHandling = [[ErrorHandling alloc] init];
    [errorHandling setErrorDataDelegate:self];
}
#pragma ErrorProtocol
- (void)passErrorDataToRoot:(NSData *)errorData {
    NSLog(@"WORKED");
}
```

So thats my code for the protocol and delegate, it almost works when the button is clicked it just never maked it to **passErrorDataToRoot** delegate method.

I am wondering if its an error in initialization, ErrorHandling.h is initialized originally when the app starts up inside the rootView, then when I get an error from a request I call ErrorHandling.m from a class called EngineRequest.m using alloc init etc... that's the only thing I can think of, that because of this extra allocation im dealing with another method but I am not sure this is the reason? I thought delegates and protocols were used to avoid this issue of reallocation.

Comment: It sounds like you've identified the problem yourself. You have two different instances of ErrorHandling? One created in `viewDidLoad` and one created somewhere else?

Comment: Have you verified that errorCodeValue is not equal to 1?

Comment: @MikeS yes I have verified that using breakpoints

Comment: @FirozeLafeer what would be or do you have any pointers/trickets for the best way to get the current instantiation of errorHandling so that I am not using multiple instances of it?

Comment: @HurkNburkS when you create the one instance, keep a pointer to it.

Comment: @HurkNburkS suggest you first verify this is your issue. At the end of your viewDidLoad add `NSLog(@"errorHandling is %p",errorHandling);` and in your alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex: add `NSLog(@"errorHandling is %p",self);` and report results

Comment: sorry that took so long just had to clear an error i managed to build in. As for the results **log1:**errorHandling is 0x1d8245b0  **log2:**errorHandling is 0x1d90bb10 so yes it would appear they are different instances...

Comment: So yes it turns out it was multiple instantiations. I solved the problem by passing a pointer to the originally initiated objectClass then using that.